# Chef client error during processing of MySQL cookbook

Tags: mysql, ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

I'm trying to provision a new server using chef-client. The process is hitting a NameError caused by an uninitialized constant 'MysqlCookbook:Helpers'.

This is the output I'm getting:

```
0.0.0.0 Compiling Cookbooks...
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0 ================================================================================
0.0.0.0 Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_client.rb
0.0.0.0 ================================================================================
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0 NameError
0.0.0.0 ---------
0.0.0.0 uninitialized constant MysqlCookbook::Helpers
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0 Cookbook Trace:
0.0.0.0 ---------------
0.0.0.0   /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_client.rb:7:in `<class:MysqlClient>'
0.0.0.0   /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_client.rb:6:in `<class:Provider>'
0.0.0.0   /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_client.rb:5:in `<class:Chef>'
0.0.0.0   /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_client.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0 Relevant File Content:
0.0.0.0 ----------------------
0.0.0.0 /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mysql/libraries/provider_mysql_client.rb:
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0   1:  require 'chef/provider/lwrp_base'
0.0.0.0   2:  require_relative 'helpers'
0.0.0.0   3:
0.0.0.0   4:  class Chef
0.0.0.0   5:    class Provider
0.0.0.0   6:      class MysqlClient < Chef::Provider::LWRPBase
0.0.0.0   7>>       include MysqlCookbook::Helpers
0.0.0.0   8:        provides :mysql_client if defined?(provides)
0.0.0.0   9:
0.0.0.0  10:        use_inline_resources if defined?(use_inline_resources)
0.0.0.0  11:
0.0.0.0  12:        def whyrun_supported?
0.0.0.0  13:          true
0.0.0.0  14:        end
0.0.0.0  15:
0.0.0.0  16:        action :create do
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0 System Info:
0.0.0.0 ------------
0.0.0.0 chef_version=12.21.31
0.0.0.0 platform=ubuntu
0.0.0.0 platform_version=16.04
0.0.0.0 ruby=ruby 2.3.5p376 (2017-09-14 revision 59905) [x86_64-linux]
0.0.0.0 program_name=chef-client worker: ppid=31986;start=12:48:17;
0.0.0.0 executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-client
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0
0.0.0.0 Running handlers:
0.0.0.0 [2018-02-07T12:48:23+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
0.0.0.0 Running handlers complete
0.0.0.0 [2018-02-07T12:48:23+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
0.0.0.0 Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 05 seconds
0.0.0.0 [2018-02-07T12:48:23+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
0.0.0.0 [2018-02-07T12:48:23+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
0.0.0.0 [2018-02-07T12:48:23+00:00] ERROR: uninitialized constant MysqlCookbook::Helpers
0.0.0.0 [2018-02-07T12:48:23+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

I've had a look at the file where it seems to be falling over (provider_mysql_client.rb) which starts off with the following code:

```
require 'chef/provider/lwrp_base'
require_relative 'helpers'

class Chef
  class Provider
    class MysqlClient < Chef::Provider::LWRPBase
      include MysqlCookbook::Helpers
      provides :mysql_client if defined?(provides)
```

I'm not a Ruby dev (my background is in PHP and JavaScript) but it looks to me like it's including the file `helpers.rb` which is in the same directory as the above file.

The contents of which start off like this:

```
module MysqlCookbook
  module HelpersBase
    require 'shellwords'

    def el6?
      return true if node['platform_family'] == 'rhel' && node['platform_version'].to_i == 6
      false
    end
```

To me this looks inconsistent with the include statement above which refers to MysqlCookbook::Helpers - this looks like it should be referred to as MysqlCookbook::HelpersBase (again I'm not a Ruby dev so I may be mistaken here).

I'm not really sure how to move forward with this and get the chef-client run to complete successfully. I have found the following issue on the cookbooks GitHub - https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/mysql/issues/540 which seems to match what's happening for me, but it doesn't have any replies so isn't particularly useful to me.

Any input/suggestions appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does it work as expected with Chef 13?

Comment: Nope, the chef client version in the above is 13.7.16

Comment: No it isn't, you can see in the error that it is `chef_version=12.21.31`.

Comment: That's odd because if I issue the command `chef-client -v` on the box I get the output `Chef: 13.7.16` - when bootstrapping the server from chefdk would it use a different version?

Answer (score 0):

The file provider_mysql_client.rb does not exist anymore in version 8.x.x of the cookbook.

Make sure you don't have old files from a previous version 7.x.x of the cookbook lying around.

If you're using Berkshelf, try to delete its cache (~/.berkself).

If you're copying everything to your target server, and then use chef zero (-z), look over there as well.